# Encoding problem in PHP while making a webservice call

Tags: php

I have the nth problem encoding related with PHP!

so the story is:

- i read a url from a file (ISO-8859). I cant change the encoding of this file for various reason I wont discuss here.
- I use that url to make a call to a rest webservice.
- the url happens to contain the symbol "è" which is conveted to � when it is loaded by the PHP engine.
- as a result the webservice returns and unexpected result because what it gets is actually the word "perch�" instead of "perchè".

I tried to force php to work with ISO-8859 by doing:

```
ini_set('default_charset', "ISO-8859");
```

The problem is that it still doesn't work and the webservice doesn't answer properly. I am sure that the webservice works as I tried to copy paste the url by hand in a browser and I received the expected data.

Comment: Side note: A URL should not contain non-ASCII - even if it usually works, they should be URL encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert data from one character set into another using [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/iconv).

Your REST web service is most likely expecting UTF-8 data, so you would have to do something like this:

```
$data = iconv("iso-8859-1", "utf-8", $data);
```

before sending the request.

Comment: Pekka, you must have magic abilities. I was reading this in the question: "i read a url from a file (ISO-8859). I cant change the encoding of this file for various reason I wont discuss here."

Comment: @hakre well, he can change the URL after reading it from the file, can't he?